# Properly adding a listener for ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an event listener for when any of my bootstrap 3 accordions that are currently in or could potentially be in "#myDiv" in the future.

This works

```
$('#myDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
//code here
});
```

However I need the id of the accordion that is open so I have tried

```
$('#myDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function (e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);
    });
```

But it never fires even though all the accordions have the class .collapse and are in #myDiv. Do I need to have an accordion present inside #myDiv at the time I assign the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation I don't think you can implement event delegation on a custom event.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.id) // this should give you the id of the currently shown accordion
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/vQgcY/)**

Comment: That does work, but I won't know all my accordion id's at the time I add the listener. Is no way to add one listener to all the accordion's inside a div?

Comment: Updated, try that. Use `document` instead of `#myDiv`

Comment: OMG! I tried that so many times, but I was using e.currentTarget! Thank you so much!